# How To Update Redux State React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

i have an object in redux state like this . the keys are actually the question ids and the values are answer ids.

```
    userProgress: [
   {
    8: '2207',
    12: '28',
    38 : '42'   
    }
]
```

Now i want to  send new values like

```
dispatch(setUserProgress({
12: '2800'
}))
```

it should find the value and update accordingly and if not found, it will add it at bottom.

Desired Result :

```
  userProgress: [
   {
    8: '2207',
    12: '2800',
    38 : '42'   
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you using a switch case in redux?

Comment: yes i am using switch

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your action is `{type:'the type',payload:{12:'2800'}}` then you can do the following:

```
return {...state, userProgress: {...state.userProgress,...payload}}
```

```js
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === 'the type') {
    return {
      ...state,
      userProgress: { ...state.userProgress, ...payload },
    };
  }
  return state;
};
console.log(
  'add new answer at the end',
  reducer(
    { userProgress: { a: 'a' } },
    { type: 'the type', payload: { newValue: 'newValue' } }
  )
);
console.log(
  'change existing value',
  reducer(
    { userProgress: { b: 'b' } },
    { type: 'the type', payload: { b: 'newValue' } }
  )
);
```

Comment: its returning the error, we cannot spread the payload. i want to find the existing value in the object and then update it. if not found, then it will add the value

Comment: @UMAIRARSHAD Before rejecting it you should have tested it. I added a snippet showing that the reducer works. If it doesn't work for you then there is something wrong with your action, the error suggests it as it is complaining about the action.payload not being able to be spread.